# How do i set my cookies to a specific domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

I have `www.mysite.com` and `static-cookieless.mysite.com`. My www site seems to be setting cookies on mysite.com thus my static site is no longer cookieless. How do i set cookies to only my www site?

I am using plain javascript (well, jquery.cookie but i know how to edit that easily)

Comment: I believe it is impossible to have a sub domain without the main domain's cookies.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.cookie = 'cookie_name=' + cookie_value+ ',path=/,domain=mydomain.com';
```

May be the link below will be useful
http://javascript.about.com/library/blwcookie.htm